# Rebuilding(Xamarin Android APP) . SQLite.cs could not be found and SQLiteAsync.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

When im rebuilding my project it comes with this error? whats the problem of it?. Im using Sqlite-net-pcl V1.4.118, Android 7.1- API25

[Sqlite.cs could not be found, and SQLite Async.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3nsi.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the full project documentation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) on github you see that you need to add a .cs file to your project:

> Source Installation SQLite-net is all contained in 1 file (I know, so
>   cool right?) and is easy to add to your project. Just add SQLite.cs to
>   your project, and you're ready to start creating tables.

you already do that? :)

Comment: Ill try these solution when i got to work later thanks. :)